# Double primary key situation on Doctrine 1, any workarounds?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple primary keys with Doctrine 1 and Symfony 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070626/multiple-primary-keys-with-doctrine-1-and-symfony-1)

I'm trying to create the following situation in Doctrine 1.x with Symfony 1.4:

```
CompanyClient:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: companyclient
  columns:
    customer_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
    company_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
  relations:
    Company:
      local: company_id
      foreign: company_id
      type: one
```

This is a simple relationship, but i have more than one primary key. Symfony model generator keeps giving me errors and more errors which leads me to think that it built the schema wrongly based on my database.

Is Doctrine capable of supporting this? If not, is there any workaround?

Comment: With Doctrine 1.2 it seems to be impossible. Do you need to use this composite primary key in a foreign key? If not, you could place `unique` condition on it. Another workaround is updating to [Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)

Comment: could you provide the schema for the company?

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine doesn't work well with composite primary keys. You should add a single (autoincrement) key. In addition, you can add a unique index constraint on customer_id + company_id.